# VB.NET Cannot access user's temp folder

Tags: vb.net

So, my problem is, i want my program to delete all files inside the user's temp folder.
To go there and see if it works, i press WIN + R and type "%temp%" and hit enter...

It shows C:\Users\EDUARD~1\AppData\Local\Temp

But if i go into the users folder, my friend's user folder is named "EduardoPC".

If i press WIN + R and type "%userprofile%", it shows this path: C:\Users\EduardoPC

Im using:

```
Dim User As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
Dim PersonalTemp As String = User & "\AppData\Local\Temp\"
```

And also tried to use:

```
Dim User As String = SystemInformation.UserName
Dim PersonalTemp As String = "C:\Users\" & User & "\AppData\Local\Temp\"
```

Both return "EDUARD~1"

My friend's account is local, and when he boots up his pc, it shows "EduardoPC" in the login screen.

Comment: `dim temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)` -- The directory name with `~1` is just the DOS name (8 characters max)

Comment: try one solution by MS https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.specialdirectories.temp?view=net-6.0 or https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=net-6.0&tabs=windows

Comment: Jimi's answer got this working, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> dim temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User) -- The directory name with ~1 is just the DOS name (8 characters max) –
> Jimi

Worked, thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).